# Insert pandas df to IBM db2

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, db2

I have a Pandas df with 80 columns and 45000 rows, i am using below connection to connect to DB2:

```
from sqlalchemy import types, select, create_engine 
eng = create_engine('ibm_db_sa://user1:pswd1@server1:50000/my_DB')
```

below is the code used to insert into my database, i am enforcing the datatype as i am not interested in having CLOB datatype.

```
cols = df_final2.dtypes[df_final2.dtypes=='object'].index
type_mapping = {col : types.VARCHAR(int(df_final2[col].str.len().max())) for col in cols }

df_final2.to_sql(name='ePIMS_Output_varchar', con=eng, if_exists = 'replace', schema='MYDBO', index=False,dtype=type_mapping)
```

I am getting below error when i try to insert it, i am getting this even if i use normal insert without using `dtype=type_mapping`

> Error 43455: Value parameters array 43455 is not
>   homogeneous with privious parameters array

please suggest me should i need to change datatype of any field. What does this error message mean, how can i fix it.